# A sequence of Operators converging to the Range projection

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

[image]

The book in question is "C* algebras and their automorphism groups" from Petersen et al. The question is simple and I imagine it should be easy, as they do not say much about that, but I am having difficulties proving that the sequence, for $x\geq 0$, $(1/n+x)^{-1}x$ converges (I suppose they mean strongly) to $[x]$, where $[x]$ is the range projection (it is defined in the picture).
I can see that the sequence is monotonically increasing and bounded, so it should converge strongly to an operator $y\in B(H)$, but why $[x]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions $f_n:[0, \infty )\to {\mathbb R}$ defined by
$$
  f_n(t)=(1/n+t)^{-1}t
  $$
are bounded by 1 and converge pointwise to the characteristic function $1_{(0,\infty )}$.  Therefore, for every positive
operator $x$,
one has  by [1, Lemma (3.5.5)] that
$f_n(x)$ converges strongly to  $1_{(0,\infty )}(x)$, which turns out to be  the range projection of $x$.

[1] *Sunder, V. S.*, Functional analysis: spectral theory, Birkhäuser Advanced Texts. Basel: Birkhäuser. ix, 241 p. (1997). [ZBL0919.46002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0919.46002).

Comment: It is quite unfortunate that one needs some kind of measurable functional calculus for that, since the book does not provide it, but it works. Either way, just to confirm, this works for separable Hilbert spaces no? Since it seems this is a standing  hypothesis in the referenced section.

Comment: Since non-separable Hilbert spaces hardly ever show up in applications, most authors simply ignore them, which I think is not a bad thing. Nevertheless I'd guess that separability is not crucial for this result.